# How does a sweep contract works?

Tags: wallets, contract-invocation, smart-contract-wallets

I received an invoice from one of my clients and they gave me a payment address to:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x4b05e01a0a2dd41071172d0c6325349921deaf2a

I'm curious to how this works as I am sending USDC to a contract, but it gets swept into another address? But the thing is who is paying for the gas cost as the contract doesn't have ETH to pay for gas. What is the purpose of sending me a contract address vs just sending me their direct eth address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an easy way for a company to provide addresses to their users, without having to worry about secure storage for private keys.

There are payment processors that give addresses to their users to accept payments in crypto. They will credit the equivalent in fiat in their accounts.

Comment: but don't they have to still worry about the contracts private key?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Contracts don't have private keys. In the best case the provider have to worry about a single private key.

Comment: so the contract is generating these user ETH addresses for deposits. and the sweep gas fee is paid by the owner of the contract ?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Yes, but obviously they charge their customers a fee for the service.